# INNER JOIN Query three tables

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

I have a three table setup in my database: members, clases, classregistration.
The class registration table has m_id and c_id columns that store the member id and class id. For example if the same member registers with more classes it will be rows of same m_id with different c_id.
I am trying to view all members that are with a particular class and I have this query but it doesn't return anything.
Any suggestions what is wrong in my query?
Thanks

```
SELECT members.member_first_name, classregistration.c_id 
FROM classregistration INNER JOIN clases
ON classregistration.c_id = clases.class_id
WHERE classregistration.c_id = 1
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: It doesn't even run because you want to `SELECT members.member_first_name` but the table `member` does not appear in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @axiac Thanks, I noticed now. I works not, but it displays that class id, but it's also getting all of the members either if they are doing that class or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
SELECT m.member_first_name, cr.c_id 
FROM classregistration cr
  INNER JOIN clases c ON cr.c_id = c.class_id
  INNER JOIN members m ON m.member_id = cr.m_id
WHERE cr.c_id = 1
```